# Login not asked by appengine with login required

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I'm using Google AppEngine to deploy a webapp and I've set my app.yaml like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: dist/assets
- url: /dist
  static_dir: dist
- url: /.*
  script: app.server.main.app
  secure: always
  login: required
```

When I open my app in Chrome Incognito mode, Flask handles the call to `/` and serve the file `index.html` (no direct access to this file, which is not even in /assets nor /dist) and then all my static resources are served (the CSS, JS present in `index.html`), and so some AJAX requests are performed too. Those AJAX requests will fail because of the `login: required` in the yaml.

The error I get in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.google.com/a/XXXXX/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=t…inue%3Dhttps://YYYYYY.appspot.com/gettoken.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://YYYYYY.appspot.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

Why are those resources served in a first time ? Accessing '/' of my app should require the login first, and then serve them.

[edit] My first post was unclear about how `index.html` is accessed

Comment: are you able to open '/' or 'index.html'? if Index.html is a static files under static directory, my guess is the static directory does not have login required

Comment: edited my post, sorry

Comment: Can you please reduce this to an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to drop the probably unrelated/misleading error? A simple `index.html` and the bare associated `app.server.main.py` file should be enough to discuss the `login: required` effectiveness. I'm unable to repro on the devserver. BTW - do you see it on the devserver as well?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your static files are served is due to the fact that they do not require login. Please note that login is only required for `/.*` pattern and has no effect on other patterns, and

> Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the app.yaml file, from top to bottom.

(see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers)

The following configuration, although not tested, should require login before serving the static files.

```
handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: dist/assets
  login: required
- url: /dist
  static_dir: dist
  login: required
- url: /.*
  script: app.server.main.app
  secure: always
  login: required
```